# How to get my cat to stop pooping and peeing on my stuff only

Tags: cats, toilet-training, stress

I'm so tired of cleaning my cat's poop and having to wash clean clothes because he pees on them. How do I train him? He has a litter box and he’s allowed to go outside. I love him to bits but I got so frustrated today I beat him up. I feel so bad, but I had a bad day and came back home to a messed up wardrobe. He wasn’t always like this.

As a kitten he always preferred to poop outside, but since mid last year he just chooses to ruin my mood. He will literally come into the house from outside, running, to poop on my stuff. How do I train him? I come from a country where sending him to the SPCA is basically killing him. He’s my baby and I love him but I am so tired right now, what do I do?

Comment: NEVER beat your pet.  You may be treating him in ways that make him resent you.  I had two cats and a girlfriend (human) many years ago.  The girlfriend liked the boy cat but hated the girl cat.  After a while, the girl cat started peeing in my girlfriend's sewing basket.  The girlfriend would scream at the girl cat, but treated the boy cat nicely.  You need to show love to your pet regardless of his behavior.  My 17-year-old cat started peeing on the floor next to her litter box, but that is normal for an old cat.  I just put down dog-training pee pads and replaced them when she peed on them.

Comment: Please look at cat-based websites for more information.  https://www.catster.com is one site that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

Changes in toileting behavior in cats are a very common sign of illness; **if you have not taken your cat to a vet** to have them evaluate the issue, **you should do so immediately**, as it sounds like **you've been letting this issue go on for a very long time without properly addressing it**. Male cats in particular can be very susceptible to urinary tract issues that can turn fatal.

**In addition**, you need to look at how you are handling cleaning of both his litter box and the other areas where he's relieved himself. **Keep the litter box clean**; if you aren't cleaning it at least once a day, start doing that. Additionally, while you might think your clothes are clean, regular detergent does not break down all the enzymes in cat urine, which will make them smell like an appropriate toilet to your cat until you properly remove them. **Get an enzymatic laundry additive** specifically for cleaning pet messes, and wash everything with that, whether or not you think it's clean. Use it every time your cat urinates or defecates on a garment. Furthermore, you'll need to **clean the surfaces below those items**, using a surface enzymatic cleaner for pet messes (appropriate to the surface you're cleaning up). Lastly, **pick up your clothes** and put them away properly. If you don't leave them where the cat can use them as a toilet, the cat won't do so.

**None of the above is a substitute for a vet visit, and a vet visit is not a substitute for any of the above cleaning steps.** You will need to do both to properly address the situation. In the meantime, **stop taking your anger out on your cat**. He isn't feeling well, and you lashing out at him isn't making him feel any better. Treat him with kindness, and make sure you address the root causes of the problem. He's not doing any of this because he's "mad at you" or "naughty," there are always underlying reasons, and unless you address those, nothing will ever change.

Answer (score -4):

poor you! Poor Cat. Sounds like you both need a fully paid luxury holiday, possibly seperate holiday destinations and stay overs. Frustration is not only a human condition but also an animal's. Wehn you return spend quality time together, change his diet, and yours, relax, meditate, excercise, entertain yourself by installing a 'rage room' I hear celebrities like Nicole Kidman have rage rooms in the homes, so they can let off steam and her hubby (cant think of his name offhand) visits opp shops and charities to get a supply of baseball bats. Try to play with him, but him a new toy or if budget restrictions apply buy loved ones and spoil him and you both. If that fails, a good wake up call is to watch some videos of abused cats and kittens. On the news, I saw how a 7 year old child with his mates was kicking and bashing a kitten only to end up killing it and throwing it in the bin. You may need to think of re training your cat. There are great videos on you tube as well of a kitten school it gives great advice, instructions and guides. God speed and God bless you and your cat.